# How to deploy nestjs project to cpanel

Tags: node.js, cpanel, nestjs

I have a problem with deploying my nestjs mailer, can not install node modules.

At first I'm uploading `package.json` file from root folder of the project and then the `dist` folder

there is the photo with its error when I'm trying install node modules
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because the request package is now deprecated. Instead, you can use other npm packages like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent). but with nestjs you don't need to install additional packages to send HTTP requests. you can use built-in [HTTP MODULE](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module) which is running axios under the hood.